# Вариация вывода страницы на основе существования данных в БД

Tags: php, laravel

Я произвожу выборку из базы данных на основе данных, полученных из формы, далее, отталкиваясь на то, существуют ли вообще эти данные, вывожу разные вариации страницы. Проблема в том, что при выборке, переменная  $idInformation всегда у меня имеет значение, либо [], либо коллекция. Как мне правильно оформить условие, чтобы под ним ничего не выполнилось?

Часть вьюшки, которая ВСЕГДА выполняется, даже когда значение в базе не найдено и $idInforms пуста, тем самым выводится всегда ненужная таблица, которая должна выводиться только, когда данные есть

```
@if ($idInforms  ?? '')
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">ID пропуска</th>
            <th colspan="2">Номер карты</th>
            <th colspan="2">Дата создания пропуска после утери/регистрации в системе</th>
            <th colspan="2">Актуальность пропуска</th>
            <th colspan="2">Полное имя</th>
            <th colspan="2">Дата получения сотрудником пропуска</th>
            <th colspan="2">Дата увольнения сотрудника</th>

        </tr>
        @foreach($idInforms ?? ''  as $idInform)
            @foreach($idInform->numbers as $number)
                @foreach($number->employees as $employee)
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">{{$number->pass_id}}</td>
                        <td colspan="2">{{$number->card_number}}</td>
                        <td colspan="2">{{$number->created_at}}</td>
                        <td colspan="2">{{$number->fired_at}}</td>
                        <td colspan="2">{{$employee->full_name}}</td>
                        <td colspan="2">{{$employee->created_at}}</td>
                        <td colspan="2">{{$employee->fired_at}}</td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
            @endforeach
        @endforeach
    </table>
```

Функция в контроллере, отвечающая за выборку данных и передачу во вьюшку

```
public function sendIdAndGetHistory(Request $request)
    {

        $this->validate($request, [
            'id' => 'required|numeric',
        ], [

            'id.required' => 'Необходимо указать номер карты',
            'id.numeric' => 'Номер карты не может быть текстом'
        ]);

        $idInformation = Pass::query()
            ->where('id', '=', \request()->get('id'))
            ->with('numbers', 'numbers.employees')
            ->get(); 

        if ($idInformation == []) {
           
            return redirect('/showHistoryForm')->with('status_of_id', 'Данного id нет в базе данных');
        }
        return view('show_history_form', [
                'idInforms' => $idInformation
            ]
        );

    }
```

Comment: просто `@if($idInforms)....` не работает?

Comment: собственно если у вас в конроллере редирект для пустого массива, то при чем тут вьюха? Проверьте в контроллере `if(!$idInformation){....}` или `count() == 0`, но в целом пустой массива рассматривается как false

Comment: @teran , спасибо, проверка коллекции с count() помогло решить задачу